# Using javascript in Aptana

Tags: javascript, aptana

I'm learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript using Aptana.

I'm trying to run JavaScript in Aptana and it does not seem to be working, no autocomplete functions and things are not logging to console when I try to debug.

Do I have to enable JavaScript in Aptana somehow? Is there a different IDE I should be using?

I see a lot of similar questions but no answers, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for people trying to use Aptana but, I gave up trying to use it. I use netbeans for HTML, CSS and javascript. I've been doing a lot of my experimenting lately with Komodo edit for node and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands from the command-line or terminal on any operating system to determine whether JDK has been installed and configured correctly:
java -version
javac -version

Comment: OP is asking about javascript, not Java. And this should be a comment on the main post.